# Can two municipalities offer reciprocal traffic enforcement over a shared border road? (US)

Tags: united-states, traffic, florida, borders

Is there any precedent/legal framework for which two municipalities whose border is defined by the middle of a road could allow for traffic enforcement for both, rather than each having jurisdiction only on their side of the road?  There are at least two border roads in Broward County, Florida that I am aware of that I have been informed that you need the "right" side of the road's law enforcement to deal with traffic enforcement.

Comment: Most states don't have such arrangements (except for case of "hot pursuit") but I can't speak to Florida in particular.

Comment: @ohwilleke I'm aware of hot pursuit, I was hoping there might be at least one example someone knew of, or a legal principle that would make it impossible

Comment: I have personally avoided tickets because the offense I allegedly committed was on the side of the road that the law enforcement officer on hand didn't have jurisdiction to issue tickets in.

Comment: @ohwilleke *sigh*  The context was going to be if such a framework existed, to lobby a pair of local municipalities to adopt it...as it is, there's a road people use to drag race at night, and neither police force will bother to come out to it

Comment: It isn't unusual for municipalities in these situations to create task forces with law enforcement officers from more than one jurisdiction working together in teams to deal with this situation, and no formal documentation of that arrangement is required.